# Is it possible to access the program Authority In Anchor

Tags: anchor, program

When running `solana program show <PROGRAM ADDDRESS>`, this is what you might get as output.

```
Program Id: C3N7mj1oCrQNkzLW90dcaV7FrSbqNiFRX6BKkXePz2tFG
Owner: BPFLoaderUpgradeab1e11111111111111111111111
ProgramData Address: Do7fGfirJpNZRZJQNp8LWaXSnL9TNjE4sNaHz4ws6ctc
Authority: 9eG8oh3jdNtn7j2KlGKTrUua31AgbLzDVkBZgT6R44aF
Last Deployed In Slot: 233995044
Data Length: 1360096 (0x14c0e0) bytes
Balance: 9.46747224 SOL
```

How can I access the `authority` property on anchor program?

Answer (score 4):

You can do it by using `ProgramData` to extract the `upgrade_authority_address`  field :

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    pub some_program_data: Account<'info, ProgramData>,
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

```
pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {
        msg!("Authority {:?}!", ctx.accounts.some_program_data.upgrade_authority_address);   
        Ok(())
    }
```

In the above code, `some_program_data` should not be the program's pubkey but it's `ProgramData Address` (you can get it with `solana program show %program_pubkey%`)

The precondition for this to work is that the owner for the program is `BPFLoaderUpgradeab1e11111111111111111111111`