Retrieve the upgrade authority of current program
Given the entrypoint of a vanilla solana program:
pub(crate) fn processor(
    program_id: &Pubkey,
    accounts: &[AccountInfo],
    instruction_data: &[u8],
) -> ProgramResult {

// Get the upgrade authority given the program ID above

Is there a way to retrieve the upgrade authority of the  program given the program ID above but from within the program? Or maybe a Sysvar I could call to retrieve account info of a public key

seems like it's possible using anchor https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/7302/1708

I was wondering if it is possible to do this using vanilla Solana without anchor,
like I can access the info in an Ed25519 instruction within a program, is it possible to call into a program like BPFLoader to get this info

You should be able to do that using the instruction sysvar. Here is an examples: https://solana.com/developers/cookbook/programs/read-multiple-instructions
 pub fn read_multiple_instruction<'info>(ctx: Context<ReadMultipleInstruction>, creator_bump: u8) -> Result<()> {
        let instruction_sysvar_account = &ctx.accounts.instruction_sysvar_account;
 
        let instruction_sysvar_account_info = instruction_sysvar_account.to_account_info();
 
        let id = "8DJXJRV8DBFjJDYyU9cTHBVK1F1CTCi6JUBDVfyBxqsT";
 
        let instruction_sysvar = instruction_sysvar_account_info.data.borrow();
 
        let mut idx = 0;
 
        let num_instructions = read_u16(&mut idx, &instruction_sysvar)
        .map_err(|_| MyError::NoInstructionFound)?;
 
        for index in 0..num_instructions {
            let mut current = 2 + (index * 2) as usize;
            let start = read_u16(&mut current, &instruction_sysvar).unwrap();
 
            current = start as usize;
            let num_accounts = read_u16(&mut current, &instruction_sysvar).unwrap();
            current += (num_accounts as usize) * (1 + 32);
            let program_id = read_pubkey(&mut current, &instruction_sysvar).unwrap();
 
            if program_id != id
            {
                msg!("Transaction had ix with program id {}", program_id);
                return Err(MyError::SuspiciousTransaction.into());
            }
        }
 
        Ok(())
    }

