Is there a way to access the a program's upgrade authority in Anchor?
My Anchor program has an instruction handler called initialize_config() that will initialize a config account and set the values inside, including the value of the authority Pubkey (which my program uses as an admin). initialize_config() will fail if the config account already exists.
However there's a moment after I deploy, before I run initialize_config(), where someone  else could run initialize_config() and set authority to their own account. A more sensible option would be to have initialize_config() set the value of authority to whatever the current program's upgrade authority is.
However I can't find any documentation on how to access the current program's upgrade authority I looked in ctx.program documentation but there's nothing on upgrade authority.
How can I access my program's upgrade authority in Anchor?

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but previous answers -> https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/7302/1708 and for native https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/16383/1708

Thanks @Jimii. Yes, that answers my question. I’ll mark this as a dupe. I do need to work out how to get the programdata address of the currently running program though.
